# TypeScript simple decorator with a String

Tags: javascript, typescript

I m studying typescript 1.5 and I m facing a little problem while trying to make a simple decorator on my property.

In fact, I need to inject a string inside my property when the app is running. Really simple, but I dont know how to process. I have read many example, but nothing looks at what I need, simply inject a string in my variable.

```
export class MyClass {

    @Log
        filePath:string;

    constructor() {

    }

    logMe() {
        console.log(this.filePath);
    }

}

function Log() {
    return function (target, key, descriptor) {
        console.log(target);
        console.log(key);
        console.log(descriptor);
        descriptor.Log = "I m logged";
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

My logMe function logs me a undefined value. I ve never used decorator before, that's why I need a really simple case.

Can you help me ?

THanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a property decorator's signature looks like this:

```
type PropertyDecorator = (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void;
```

Change your decorator to match this signature.

Second, since you are not passing any arguments to the decorator, you should define your parameters directly on the `Log` function.

At this point, you can assign your string to the corresponding prototype property the decorator is defined on. You should end up with the following:

```
function Log(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
    target[propertyKey] = "I'm logged";
}
```

Now when running your method, it will output `I'm logged` by default:

```
var c = new MyClass();
c.logMe(); // outputs: I'm logged
c.filePath = "test";
c.logMe(); // outputs: test
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Log%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filePath%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20logMe()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.filePath)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Ac.logMe()%3B%20%2F%2F%20I'm%20logged%0D%0Ac.filePath%20%3D%20%22test%22%3B%0D%0Ac.logMe()%3B%20%2F%2F%20test%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Log(target%3A%20Object%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%20%7C%20symbol)%20%7B%0D%0A%09target%5BpropertyKey%5D%20%3D%20%22I'm%20logged%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)

---

Just so you can understand this a bit better, here's an example with arguments:

```
function Log(defaultValue = "I'm logged") {
    return function (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
        target[propertyKey] = defaultValue;
    };
}
```

Be aware though that when doing this you must always decorate with parentheses like so: `@Log()`. It doesn't give an error if you just do `@Log`. There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3246) about this.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%40Log()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filePath%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%40Log(%22Test%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filePath2%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20logMe()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.filePath)%3B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(this.filePath2)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Ac.logMe()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Log(defaultValue%20%3D%20%22I'm%20logged%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20function%20(target%3A%20Object%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%20%7C%20symbol)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09target%5BpropertyKey%5D%20%3D%20defaultValue%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Really thank you for this answer. Just one last thing, can you give the Method and Class signature for version 1.5 ? It seems that older uses a class called TypedPropertyDescriptor that I cant access. I dont want to reopen a topic only for this :-/ . Have a nice day and thank you again

Comment: @Skahrz hmmm.. that's strange. You can find the signatures in [the proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2249) and in [core.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/core.d.ts#L1159). Both say it's still using a `TypedPropertyDescriptor` though.